# Get unique visitors to a city

Tags: postgresql

I have a city table like this

```
| id | name |
```

A users table

```
| id | forename | surname
```

And a visitors table

```
| id | user | city | createdAt
```

I am trying to get a list of unique users that have visited a city, I want it to be each persons latest visit, and dont show their previous visits

Here is my query

```
select distinct "user", "forename", "surname" 
      from "visitors" 
      inner join "users" on "visitors"."user" = "users"."id"     
      where "city" = 1
```

This gives the correct records but I cant select or order by any of the fields on the visitors table. If i add visitors.id in the select clause it ignores the distinct

Alternatively when inserting, I could just update their existing visit instead of a new record every time. But I figured its best pracitse to keep records of every visit instead of updating but if this will make my problem easily solvable while still being good practise I will do that

Thankyou

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you are actually using!

Comment: @Shadow wouldnt they both apply in this case?

Comment: no double quotes are only valid in Postgres

Comment: Your query above would result in a syntax error under default mysql settings to start with. So, no, you need to tag the one that you use.

Comment: ok makes sense, thanks i changed it

Comment: @Austin the createdAt field, since the record i would like to show for each user, would be their most recent visit. When I add this to the select clause, it returns duplicate records. It only seems to work when I dont select any visitors fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `DISTINCT ON`. It only keeps the first row for each user. The `ORDER BY` the creation timestamp determines which record is first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u."id")
       u."id",
       u."forename",
       u."surname"
       FROM "visitors" v
            INNER JOIN "users" u
                       ON v."user" = u."id"
       WHERE v."city" = 1
       ORDER BY u."id" ASC,
                v."createdat" DESC;
```